# How to remove URL Parameter when Submit on Search Engine

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, search-engine, url-parameters

I built my own search engine at my website.

I want the output of my search at URL when I click Submit (as Search Button) is :

```
http://inindonesia.org/marketplace/tags/oleh-oleh-khas-medan
```

But, When I click Submit (search button), the output is :

```
http://inindonesia.org/marketplace/tags/?search=oleh+oleh+khas+medan&hidden=oleh-oleh-khas-medan&Submit=Cari+Produk
```

My code is :

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="/marketplace/tags/(i want this get parameter from the value input id "hidden", example : oleh-oleh-khas-medan)" method="GET">
    <table border="0" border="0" cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="2px" width="100%" bgcolor="">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:12px; text-align:left;" width="80%">
                <input id="search" name="search" type="text"/><input id="hidden" name="hidden" type="hidden"/>
            </td>
            <td style="font-size:12px; text-align:right;" width="20%">
                <input id="searchsubmit" name="Submit" value="Cari Produk" type="submit">
```

FYI: I am using Wordpress at my site.

Any ideas to change the url parameter like I want? 
Thanks

Comment: To get the exact described behaviour, you'd change the method to `POST`, add an `onsubmit` handler, append the `input`'s value to the `action` url, and re-submit the form data (or use `window.location.href = http://inindonesia.org/marketplace/tags/ + input value` and `return false;` in the onsubmit event.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..... or You want something Different? Explain?

**HTML**

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="" onsubmit="return submitform()" method="POST">
    <table border="0" border="0" cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="2px" width="100%" bgcolor="">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:12px; text-align:left;" width="80%">
                <input id="search" name="search" type="text"/><input id="hidden" name="hidden" type="hidden"/>
            </td>
            <td style="font-size:12px; text-align:right;" width="20%">
                <input id="searchsubmit" name="Submit" value="Cari Produk" type="submit">
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
    var hiddenFieldValue    =   document.getElementById('search').value;
        hiddenFieldValue    =   hiddenFieldValue.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        //alert(location.host+'/marketplace/tags/'+hiddenFieldValue);
        window.location         =   'http://'+location.host+'/marketplace/tags/'+hiddenFieldValue;
}
</script>
```

Comment: thankyou so much @Zeeshan.. but why it still redirect to my location host? you can check at my website : www.inindonesia.org.. I have done add submitform() function to my script.. maybe because I using wordpress? Please advice, thankyou..

Comment: @MimmaRuchaini i have tested its working fine, what exactly problem are you getting in this, its redirecting fine, to the searched keyword location like if i search test abc, its redirecting me to http://inindonesia.org/marketplace/tags/test-abc, you can check by using this line. from console (window.location         =   'http://'+location.host+'/marketplace/tags/test-abc')

Comment: yes.. it works fine because it works on keydown function... You can try 1. Type anything, 2. Click whatever you want when autocomplete appear, 3. and then click 'Cari Product' button.. It appear alert with right url, but when I click OK on alert, its redirect to inindonesia.org, with chaotic display.. In other words, I have 2 function in my own search engine.. 1. When keydown function, 2. When click 'Cari Product' function then redirect.. Thankyou @Zeeshan :)